# Read transaction logs of another Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, etherscan, events

I have to track user activity in DEX smart contract and do some validation/operation based on that information.

DEX itself does not API to retrieve that info, but emit events, so is there any way to read transaction logs from the smart contract?

**UPDATE 1**

DEX smart contract in TRON blockchain:
https://tronscan.org/#/contract/TQn9Y2khEsLJW1ChVWFMSMeRDow5KcbLSE/code

**UPDATE 2**

Here the Smart Contract itself with the events I am interested:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

interface IJustswapExchange {
  event TokenPurchase(address indexed buyer, uint256 indexed trx_sold, uint256 indexed tokens_bought);
  event TrxPurchase(address indexed buyer, uint256 indexed tokens_sold, uint256 indexed trx_bought);
  event AddLiquidity(address indexed provider, uint256 indexed trx_amount, uint256 indexed token_amount);
  event RemoveLiquidity(address indexed provider, uint256 indexed trx_amount, uint256 indexed token_amount);

 /**
   Smart contract code goes here ...
 **/
}
```

P.S. If possible I will need events filtered by the first argument.

**UPDATE 3**

Ethereum equivalent contract with events:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x1f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984#code

```
contract Uni {
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 amount);
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is...

Comment: Can you provide details? I am new to blockchain, will be grateful if you share resources))

Comment: Can you provide the contract source code, and its address on the network?

Comment: Its Justswap (analog of uniswap for TRON) 
Here is the contract itself:
https://tronscan.org/#/contract/TQn9Y2khEsLJW1ChVWFMSMeRDow5KcbLSE/code

Comment: Post the code as part of your question **in plain text** (no links or images), and only the relevant code (in your case, the prototype of the event that you're interested in).

Comment: See update above

Comment: Where is the contract deployed?

Comment: In TRON blockchain at specified link. Here is address: TQn9Y2khEsLJW1ChVWFMSMeRDow5KcbLSE

Comment: This is not an ethereum address!!!

Comment: I said its Tron, but everything is similar.

Comment: I'll add ethereum equivalent as well